# Android XMLRPC Exception handling

Tags: android, exception, xml-rpc

I wanted to ask what is the best way to handle an exception when you are calling a XMLRPC function and the server is down or not responding. I have the following code:

```
try
    {           
        mXmlRpcClient.call(mRequestVariantsFunc, SessionID, newID, "1970-01-01T00:00:00+00" ,"1970-01-01T00:00:00+00");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code above works alright when the server is running but when its down I get a black screen and the phone freezes. The rest of the code is running while in black screen but no exception is thrown. Is there a way to handle this problem in case the server is down not to go into a black screen?

Answer (score 0):

For me, in another tool there is a message going via a handler to indicate progress. Also, a seperate class to handle exceptions is nice to have.

If you have the same library as me, here my example for what it's worth:

```
package hha.zhongcan.communication;

import java.net.URI;

import android.os.Handler;

import android.util.Log;
import hha.zhongcan.framework.Citem;
import hha.zhongcan.framework.Configuration;
import hha.zhongcan.framework.CtimeFrame;
import hha.zhongcan.framework.Ctransaction;
import hha.zhongcan.microfood.AskTableDialog;
import hha.zhongcan.resources.Global;
import org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException;

interface XMLRPCMethodCallback 
{
    void callFinished(Object result);
}

/** Messages to send to the PC at high level. Receive the menu items, pages, transactions.
 *  Create fake data for the demo.
 *  
 * @author mensfort
 *
 */
public class Cmessage
{
    static private Cmessage     m_message =null;
    private static URI          m_uri;
    public static XMLRPCClient  m_client;
    private final static String TAG="message";
    private boolean             m_connected =false;
    private int m_pingId =0;
    private int m_lost =0;
    private int m_wait =0;
    private boolean m_sendTransactions =true;
    private Handler m_updateHandler = new Handler(); 
    boolean m_getItems = false;
    boolean m_getPages = false;
    private static Global m_global =null;
    private int m_countTransactions =10;
    private int transactionMessageCount =0;
    private long getValue( String s)
    {
        try
        {
            if ( s.startsWith("0x") || s.startsWith("0X"))
            {
                s =s.substring(2);
                while (s.startsWith("0"))
                {
                    s=s.substring(1);
                }
                if ( s.length() ==0)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                return Long.parseLong(s, 16);  
            }
            if ( s=="")
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return Long.parseLong(s);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /// @brief New thread for running ask-table.
    private Runnable messageTask = new Runnable() 
    {
        //@override
        public void run() 
        {
            if ( m_getItems)
            {
                m_getItems =false;
                getMenuItems();
            }
            else if ( m_getPages)
            {
                m_getPages =false;
                getMenuPages();
            }
            else if ( m_sendTransactions)
            {
                // If I have sth to send and I'm not in page mode, then start sending items.
                sendTransactions();
                m_wait =2;
            }
            else if ( Configuration.getInstance().isDemo())
            {
                m_connected =true;
                next();
            }
            else if ( m_wait>0)
            {
                m_wait--;
                next();
            }
            else if ( --m_countTransactions<=0)
            {
                 sendMessage_getTransactions();
                 m_countTransactions =5;
            }
            else
            {
                 // Update this screen every 10 seconds.
                 sendConnected();
            }           
        }
    };  

    /** @brief At startup start the first message after a second.
     */
    private Cmessage()
    {
        m_updateHandler.postDelayed( messageTask, 1000);
    }

    /** @brief Set the address and port.
     * 
     * @param address [in] Address to use.
     * @param port [in] Port to use.
     */
    public void setPath( String address, Integer port)
    {
        m_uri = URI.create("http://192.168.0.105:9876");
        m_client  =new XMLRPCClient( m_uri); 
    }

    /** @brief Singleton implementation, only this instance can send messages.
     * 
     * @return Pointer to the singleton.
     */
    public static Cmessage getInstance()
    {
        if ( m_message ==null)
        {
            m_message =new Cmessage();
            m_global  =Global.getInstance();
        }
        return m_message;
    }

    /** @brief In a second, the next command can be send to the PC.
     */
    public void next()
    {
        m_updateHandler.postDelayed( messageTask, 1000);
    }

    /** @brief Check if we are connected to the PC. 
     * 
     * @return true when connected.
     */
    public boolean isConnected()
    {
        return m_connected;
    }

    /** @brief Send Ping message, just to check the connection status. 
     */
    public void sendConnected()
    {
        {
            XMLRPCMethod method =new XMLRPCMethod( "ping", new XMLRPCMethodCallback() {
                public void callFinished(Object result) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        String s = (String) (result);
                        if ( s.equals("bart"))
                        {
                            m_lost =0;
                            m_connected =true;
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        m_connected =false;
                        m_lost++;
                    }
                }
            });
            Object[] params ={ m_pingId++ }; // {};
            method.call(params);
        }
        if ( ++m_lost>2)
        {
            m_connected =false;
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage_getConfiguration() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    private void createMenuFrom( Object [] arrY)
    {
        if ( arrY.length >0)
        {
            m_global.itemDB.clean();
        }
        int v=(int)(arrY.length/9);
        int lvl=1;
        for (int y=0; y<arrY.length; y++)  
        {
            if ( y==lvl*v)
            {
                setSlider(lvl++);
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "item " + y);
            Object[] arrX = (Object[]) arrY[y];
            int id =(Integer) arrX[0];
            String alias =(String) arrX[1];
            String local =(String) arrX[2];                         
            String chinese =(String) arrX[3];
            int restaurant_price =(Integer) arrX[4];
            int takeaway_price =(Integer) arrX[5];
            int level =(Integer) arrX[6];
            int page =(Integer) arrX[7];
            int sequence =(Integer) arrX[8];
            int colour_text = (int)(getValue( (String) arrX[9])&0xffffffff);
            int colour_background = (int)(getValue( (String) arrX[10])&0xffffffff);
            int colour_selected_text = (int)(getValue( (String) arrX[11])&0xffffffff);
            int colour_selected_background = (int)(getValue( (String) arrX[12])&0xffffffff);
            int colour_background2 = (int)(getValue( (String) arrX[13])&0xffffffff);
            int colour_selected_background2 = (int)(getValue( (String) arrX[14])&0xffffffff);
            if ( m_global.mainMenuHandler !=null)
            {
    //                  m_global.mainMenuHandler.obtainMessage( y, "UPDATE_MENU_SLIDEBAR "+y).sendToTarget();

            }
            m_global.itemDB.insert( id, alias, local, chinese, restaurant_price, 
                                  takeaway_price, (byte)level, (byte)page, (short)sequence, 
                                  colour_text, colour_background, colour_selected_text, 
                                  colour_selected_background, colour_background2, 
                                  colour_selected_background2);
        }
        m_global.itemDB.complete();
        Log.i(TAG, "Items received correct.");
    }

    /** Indicate that we want to get the menu card.
     */
    public void sendMessage_getMenuItems() 
    {
        m_getItems = true;
        m_getPages = true;
    }

    /** @brief Get the menu items. */
    public void getMenuItems() 
    {
        boolean demo =Configuration.getInstance().isDemo();
        if (demo ==true)
        {
            createMenuFrom( demoMenu.items);        
            next();
        }
        else
        {
            XMLRPCMethod method =new XMLRPCMethod( "items", new XMLRPCMethodCallback() {
                public void callFinished(Object result) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        m_global.itemDB.deleteAll();
                        m_global.itemDB.clean();
                        Object[] arrY = (Object[]) result;
                        createMenuFrom( arrY);
                        m_connected =true;
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        m_connected =false;
                    }
                }
            });
            Object[] params = {};
            if ( m_global.mainMenuHandler !=null)
            {
                m_global.mainMenuHandler.obtainMessage( 1, "UPDATE_MENU_SLIDEBAR 1").sendToTarget();
            }
            method.call(params);
            if ( m_global.mainMenuHandler !=null)
            {
                m_global.mainMenuHandler.obtainMessage( 1, "UPDATE_MENU_SLIDEBAR 5").sendToTarget();
            }
        }
    }

    /** Call to get all transactions from the server, including payments, items and time-frames. */
    public void sendMessage_sendTransactions() 
    {
        m_sendTransactions =true;
    }

    /** Set slider to a value 1..10 
     * 
     * @param n [in] 0..10
     */
    private void setSlider( int n)
    {
        if ( m_global.mainMenuHandler !=null)
        {
            m_global.mainMenuHandler.obtainMessage( 0, "UPDATE_MENU_SLIDEBAR "+n).sendToTarget();
        }
    }

    /** After sending the orders, the database can be cleaned...
     */
    private void cleanDatabase()
    {
        try 
        {
            m_global.transactionDB.clean();
            m_global.timeFrameDB.clean();
            m_global.transactionItemDB.clean();
            m_connected =true;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            m_connected =false;
        }
    }

    /** Send all transaction */
    private void sendTransactions()
    {
        if ( m_global.transactionDB.size() ==0)
        {
            m_sendTransactions =false;
            cleanDatabase();
            next();
            return;
        }
        if ( Configuration.getInstance().isDemo())
        {
            cleanDatabase();
            try
            {
                m_global.askTableHandler.obtainMessage( AskTableDialog.MESSAGE_DATA_SENT,-1,-1, -1).sendToTarget();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            m_sendTransactions =false;
        }
        XMLRPCMethod method =new XMLRPCMethod( "orders", new XMLRPCMethodCallback() 
        {
            public void callFinished(Object result) 
            {
                cleanDatabase();
                m_global.askTableHandler.obtainMessage( AskTableDialog.MESSAGE_DATA_SENT,-1,-1, -1).sendToTarget();
                m_sendTransactions =false;
            }
        });
        Object[][] transaction =m_global.transactionDB.get();
        Object[][] timeFrame   =m_global.timeFrameDB.get();
        Object[][] item        =m_global.transactionItemDB.get();

        Object[] params ={ transaction,timeFrame,item };

        //{
        //  transaction, timeFrame, item
        //}/;
        if ( transaction ==null || timeFrame ==null || item ==null)
        {
            cleanDatabase();
            Log.e( TAG,"Database problem!!");
        }
        method.call( params);
    }

    /// Call to get all transactions from the server, including payments, items and time-frames.
    public void sendMessage_getTransactions() 
    {
        if ( m_global.transactionDB.size() >0)
        {
            return;
        }
        if ( m_global.timeFrameDB.size() >0)
        {
            return;
        }
        if ( m_global.transactionItemDB.size() >0)
        {
            return;
        }
        XMLRPCMethod method =new XMLRPCMethod( "get_transactions", new XMLRPCMethodCallback() 
        {
            public void callFinished(Object result) 
            {
                m_countTransactions =10;
                m_connected =true;
                if ( m_global.transactionDB.size() >0)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Transaction DB not empty.");
                    return;
                }
                if ( m_global.timeFrameDB.size() >0)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Time Frame DB not empty.");
                    return;
                }
                if ( m_global.transactionItemDB.size() >0)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Transaction Item DB not empty.");
                    return;
                }
                try 
                {
                    m_global.transactionList.clean();               
                    Object[] arrY = (Object[]) result;
                    Object[] transactions =(Object[]) arrY[0];
                    Object[] timeFrames   =(Object[]) arrY[1];
                    Object[] items        =(Object[]) arrY[2];
                    //Object[] payments     =(Object[]) arrY[3];

                    for (int y=0; y<transactions.length; y++) 
                    {
                        Object[] trx = (Object[]) transactions[y];
                        int id = Integer.valueOf(trx[0].toString());
                        String tme =trx[1].toString();
                        String name =trx[2].toString();
                        int customer_id =Integer.valueOf( trx[3].toString());
                        int status =Integer.valueOf( trx[4].toString());
                        int total =Integer.valueOf( trx[5].toString());
                        Ctransaction t=new Ctransaction( id, name, tme, status, customer_id, total);
                        m_global.transactionList.insert( t);
                    }
                    for (int y=0; y<timeFrames.length; y++) 
                    {
                        Object[] trx = (Object[]) timeFrames[y];
                        int id = Integer.valueOf( trx[0].toString());
                        int tfi =Integer.valueOf( trx[1].toString());
                        int waiter =Integer.valueOf( trx[2].toString());
                        String start_time =trx[3].toString();
                        String end_time =trx[4].toString();
                        int transaction_id =Integer.valueOf( trx[5].toString());
                        int device_id =Integer.valueOf( trx[6].toString());
                        CtimeFrame c =new CtimeFrame( id, (short)tfi, waiter, 
                                                      start_time, end_time, 
                                                      transaction_id, device_id);
                        m_global.transactionList.insert( c);
                    }
                    for (int y=0; y<items.length; y++) 
                    {
                        Object[] trx = (Object[]) items[y];
                        //int id = (Integer) trx[0];
                        long menu_item_id =Long.valueOf( trx[1].toString());
                        int sequence =Integer.valueOf( trx[2].toString());
                        int time_frame_index =Integer.valueOf( trx[3].toString());
                        int deleted_time_frame_index =Integer.valueOf( trx[4].toString());
                        long transaction_id =Long.valueOf( trx[5].toString());
                        int quantity =Integer.valueOf( trx[6].toString());
                        int level =Integer.valueOf( trx[7].toString());
                        int deleted =Integer.valueOf( trx[8].toString());
                        int portion =Integer.valueOf( trx[9].toString());
                        int orig_price =Integer.valueOf( trx[10].toString());
                        int unit_price =Integer.valueOf( trx[11].toString());
                        String time =trx[12].toString();                    
                        Citem i=new Citem( menu_item_id, y, (short)sequence, 
                                           (short)time_frame_index, 
                                           (short)deleted_time_frame_index,
                                           transaction_id, quantity, 
                                           (byte)level, deleted, (byte)portion, unit_price, orig_price, time);
                        m_global.transactionList.insert( i);
                    }
                    //for (int y=0; y<payments.length; y++) 
                    //{
                        //Object[] pay = (Object[]) payments[y];
                        //int id = (Integer) pay[0];
                        //String time =(String) pay[1];
                        //int money_received =(Integer) pay[2];
                        //int customer_id =(Integer) pay[3];
                        //int pay_method =(Integer) pay[4];
                        //int partial_index =(Integer) pay[5];
                        //global.paymentsDB.insert( id, time, money_received, customer_id, pay_method, partial_index);
                    //}
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    m_connected =false;
                }
            }
        });
        Object[] params = { transactionMessageCount++ };
        method.call(params);
    }

    /// Call, but not in main thread, answer comes in a thread.
    private void getMenuPages() 
    {
        if ( Configuration.getInstance().isDemo())
        {
            decodePages( demoMenu.pages);
            next();
            return;
        }
        XMLRPCMethod method =new XMLRPCMethod( "pages", new XMLRPCMethodCallback() 
        {
            public void callFinished(Object result) 
            {
                decodePages( result);
            }
        });
        setSlider(7);
        Object[] params = {};
        method.call(params);
        setSlider(8);
    }

    /**  
     * @brief Convert an array to page data. 
     * @param result [in] array with local, chinese names.
     */
    private void decodePages( Object result)
    {
        try 
        {
            m_global.pageDB.clean();
            Object[] arrY = (Object[]) result;
            setSlider(9);
            for (int y=0; y<arrY.length; y++) 
            {
                Object[] arrX = (Object[]) arrY[y];
                int id = (Integer) arrX[0];
                String local =(String) arrX[1];
                String chinese =(String) arrX[2];
                String lc =local.replace( "'", "''");
                String ch =chinese.replace( "'", "''");
                m_global.pageDB.insert( id, lc, ch);
            }
            m_connected =true;
            if ( m_global.mainMenuHandler !=null)
            {
                m_global.mainMenuHandler.obtainMessage( 0, "UPDATE_MENU_READY").sendToTarget();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            m_connected =false;
        }
    }

    class XMLRPCMethod extends Thread 
    {
        private String method;
        private Object[] params;
        private Handler handler;
        private XMLRPCMethodCallback callBack;
        public XMLRPCMethod(String method, XMLRPCMethodCallback callBack) 
        {
            this.method = method;
            this.callBack = callBack;
            handler = new Handler();
        }
        public void call() 
        {
            call(null);
        }
        public void call(Object[] params) 
        {
            this.params = params;
            start();
        }
        //@Override
        public void run() 
        {
             synchronized(this) 
             {
                try 
                {
                    final long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    final Object result = m_client.callEx(method, params);
                    final long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            Log.i(TAG, "XML-RPC call took " + (t1-t0) + "ms");
                            callBack.callFinished(result);
                            next();
                        }
                    });
                } 
                catch (final XMLRPCFault e) 
                {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Fault message: " + e.getFaultString() + "\nFault code: " + e.getFaultCode());
                            Log.d("Test", "error", e);
                            next();
                        }
                    });
                } 
                catch (final XMLRPCException e) 
                {
                    next();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            Throwable couse = e.getCause();
                            if (couse instanceof HttpHostConnectException) 
                            {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot connect to " + m_uri.getHost() + "\nMake sure server.py on your development host is running !!!");
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, "error", e);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    next();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
         }
    }
}
```